# Get ordered product count in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

We are using magento 1.9. In that

How to get ordered product count not order qty of product. I want to how many product is there in that order?

I am using this but it showing ordered qty only

```
 <?php 
        $_order = $this->getOrder(); //call the order
        echo $order_qty = floor($_order->getData('total_qty_ordered')); //get qty of all items rounded to full number (without 3.0000 or so)
        //echo $order_qty;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php echo $_order->getTotalItemCount();?>
```

**For eg.**

[image]

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Can share your code ???

Comment: code means i jus want to display how many product available in sales order page backend

Comment: ChecK
$order  = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
echo  '<pre>';
print_r($order);

Comment: and give response me :)

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: but where is the order data in response? I think u r going same wrong way :)

Comment: i don't know it's default magento only

Comment: Updated ans check now

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems()` instead of `$items =  $order->getAllItems()`.

getAllItems gets the configurable along with its associated simple product.

```
echo $NumberOfItem = count($items);
```

so its up to you to use in your way.

Comment: No it's not working

Answer (score 0):

For order Item count use below code.

```
$items = $order->getAllItems();

$itemcount = count($items);
```

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: may be it help you : 

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId); then use upper code.