# Get order product item count in order success page - Magento 2

Tags: product, orders, phtml, count

I want get number of product order in order success page. This found solution magento 1.9 visit [Get ordered product count in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98624/get-ordered-product-count-in-magento/)

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php echo $_order->getTotalItemCount();?>
```

but I didn't get any solution in Magento 2

If anyone know Get order product item count in order success page phtml file, please share with me,Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom block for onepage which calculates & returns the product count.

app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Onepage/Success/productitemcount

Then you'd be able to grab it on the success page.